# Finder opens or sends the wrong file (El Capitan + Sierra)

Tags: finder

At seemingly random occurrence, these days a few times per day, finder seems to confuse files.

When opening a file from the column view list, or when dragging the file into another application (as an attachment for example), the wrong file is opened or sent. Usually it is the next or previous file in the list of files that I'm looking at.

When the wrong file is opened I can notice it immediately, but when sending the wrong file there is no way of telling, even in the email the filename I intended will show, but the recipient will receive another file.

It has been happening on two computers, one running el capitan (10.11.6), the other running sierra.

I'm not sure if this is related, but I always use the Column view in finder, I still have to test if it happens in other views as well.

Does anyone have a clue why this is happening?

Comment: As it's affecting 2 machines on 2 OSes, let's assume it's not inherent in the OS or hardware - or we'd have heard of this happening before. Best guess would be it's some 3rd party app/utility that is common to both. I don't know of anywhere else to start.

Comment: @Tetsujin hmm yes, these two machines have a few 3rd party apps in commmon that another machine without the bug does not have, so yes this might be where to look. Adobe Creative Cloud, Postbox and Itsycal, the last one less common than the other two so will start without that one.

Comment: mhm, I'd doubt it would be CC, it's too common & would have likely thrown up the symptom somewhere, for someone, before now. I don't know the other two, so they'd be my first place to start too.